# Accessing custom settings in Email templates

Tags: customsetting

Is it possibble to access the custom settings in Email Templates directly? (I know I can refer the custom settings in formula, and then refer this formula field in the email template)

I am facing an issue where, I get a different URL in the email alert than what I see in the browser's address bar. Please refer the below question for more details:

[Mismatch in Links recieved through email alerts and User getting redirected to home page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8645/mismatch-in-links-recieved-through-email-alerts-and-user-getting-redirected-to-h)

So as a last option, I was thinking to have a custom settings that will store the hardcoded URL and refer it in the Email Template. I feel that this is not a feasible solution, but I am not able to find any other solution.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can access Hierarchical Custom Settings directly in Visualforce Email Templates.

```
{!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}
```

Comment: So I will need to convert all my HTML email templates to Visualforce Email templates?